# error comping c to (windows)exe on linux with mingw

Tags: c, linux, mingw, exe, pdcurses

I installed the mingw stuff from yaourt on arch linux but when i type

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc tom.c ncurses_functions.c terminal_functions.c list_functions.c -o -lpdcurses tom_windows.exe
```

I get:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: tom_windows.exe: No such file or directory
```

It must be something simple but I don't know what!

Comment: `-o` means the next argument is the output filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc tom.c ncurses_functions.c terminal_functions.c list_functions.c -o tom_windows.exe -lpdcurses
```

Comment: If the answer is useful for you, consider accepting it as the correct one, gives both you and @Lukasz reputation

Comment: yeah I know but I needed to wait for 10 minutes to do so and I forgot

Answer (score 1):

The argument after `-o` is the output filename. In your case, you've told it to output to a file called `-lpdcurses`. Then you've told it to compile `tom_windows.exe` (as if it was a source file).

Swap the order of `-o` and `-lpdcurses`.